# How to avoid red line through https:// OR display external webpage as landing page in customer community

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, home-page-component, landing-page

We are building a customer community and I'm having trouble with the home page.  Currently I'm using a VisualForce page with an iframe to display a welcome page that our marketing team built in HubSpot.  It displays in Chrome and IE but throws warnings that it's not secure.  Is there a way to display that page in the customer community without the warnings?

Or, when a customer logs into the community, could they be redirected to the HubSpot page and then links from that page take them back into the customer community?

Or is there a better/easier way?  If possible I'd like to avoid recreating the whole page over again...

Comment: Is your HubSpot page using http or https? What is the exact error you are getting? Is it "This page contains both secure and insecure items"?

Comment: HubSpot page uses http.  Yes, the error in IE is that at first it's only displaying secure items but you can click for all.  In Chrome, I clicked the shield at the right of the URL bar and it then displayed all data but left a red line through the https part of the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VisualForce page is using `https://` (SSL) and it is trying to use a non-SSL `http://`address in the iFrame then you will get an error complaining that  "This page contains both secure and nonsecure items".

It is possible to [turn off that error](http://agsci.psu.edu/it/how-to/turn-off-this-page-contains-both-secure-and-nonsecure-items-prompts) via the browser but it would mean all users having to change their browser settings. The correct solution is to implement SSL on the server that hosts the HubSpot page so that your iFrame changes from:

```
<iframe src="http://www.blah.com">
```

to:

```
<iframe src="https://www.blah.com">
```

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge.  I really appreciate your help!  Is it difficult to implement SSL on the site?  Can it be done for just one page or would it have to be done for all?

Comment: It would depend on the server that its running on. It could already be setup, try changing `http` to `https` in your iframe to see if it is.  [Here](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-ssl) are the details for setting it up on Tomcat for an example of what is involved.

Comment: Apparently HubSpot does not support SSL over HTTPS.  Thank you helping to eliminate that option.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't have any other ideas I'm afraid.